# How to alter elements of a UILabel after I've added it to the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a program where I am making a grid of tiles (all being UILabels) and I need to be able to change the text of the UILabel in my code on the fly, How my program currently functions is it just keeps creating new UILabels overtop so every time I make a move on this tile map it reprints a new map over the old one instead of altering the original.

```
mapLabels[w][h] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cursor.x, cursor.y, tileSize, tileSize)];

mapLabels[w][h].text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", map[w][h]];

mapLabels[w][h].backgroundColor = [self FindTileColor:map[w][h]];

mapLabels[w][h].textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

[self.view addSubview:mapLabels[w][h]];
```

I set all the labels and their location like ^ this in a for loop, can someone show me how to alter the labels

Comment: The same way that you are creating a new label and setting the fields, simply reference the label that you want to change, and change the fields/properties/etc that you want. Unless you built your program in a way that this is not currently possible for you?

Comment: Did `mapLabels[w][h].text = @"new-text";` not work?

Comment: I'm not sure if the c style array has anything to do with it, but I've done this with regular NSArray's and that worked just fine. Perhaps you can switch to NSArray and see if it works?

Comment: Also, how did you define the array?

Comment: UILabel *mapLabels[kMapSize][kMapSize];

Comment: Well, I just tried it and it works fine for me. So it looks like there is a problem somewhere else in your code. Could you post some more relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You should give each label a tag

```
mapLabels[w][h].tag = whatevertag
```

Then when you want to access one you can do

```
[self.view viewWithTag:whatevertag]
```

The tag will be an int that you can increment each time you add a new label.

OR, why can't you just use the array you already have?

Comment: I am using the array I already have but whenever I try to change it it doesn't do anything for example if i would write... mapLabel[w][h].text = blahblah after i have added it to the view it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

you can access the views you added with `addSubview`
by using the `self.view.subviews` property, which is an NSArray of the views you added. 
You could try:

```
UILabel * labelref = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
labelref.text = @"mytext";
```

Comment: are you saying its because I have the UILabels in a classic C array instead of an NSArray

Comment: I just wanted to try a different way of accessing the views: if you are seeing them on screen you can then access them using the view hierarchy.